# How to convert Jupyter markdown to PDF via latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to convert my Jupyter Notebook markdown to a PDF via latex on mac. I get the following error:

nbconvert failed: xelatex not found on PATH, if you have not installed xelatex you may need to do so. Find further instructions at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex.

I have installed MacTex, so what I need should be on my computer, but I'm not that competent with file paths and the like yet to sort out what's going on. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code allows you to export a Jupyter notebook to PDF:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK22B.png
[Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)

Opening your notebook in VS Code might at least let you do the PDF export.